# Assign to an element of a struct of a pointer array don't work (null)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm new here and in programming. My problem is when i try to asign a value to a proprerty of a array pointers struct, it does not work. The following code without struct work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *array;
    int size = 10;
    array = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i * i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
}
```

But when i put struct it does print (null):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Person
{
    unsigned char name;
} Person;

int main()
{
    Person *personArray;
    int size = 10;
    personArray = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        unsigned char name = "Person_name"; //[Warning] initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
        personArray[i].name = name;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", personArray[i].name); //Print (null)
    }
}
```

Why this happens? 
Sorry for anything if I'm new here.

Thank you, the following code work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Person
{
    unsigned char *name;
} Person;

int main()
{
    Person *personArray;
    int size = 10;
    personArray = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(Person) * size);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        unsigned char *name = "Person_name";
        personArray[i].name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1); //[Warning] incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strlen'
        strcpy(personArray[i].name, name); //[Warning] incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strcpy'
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", personArray[i].name);
        free(personArray[i].name);
    }

    free(personArray);
}
```

Comment: Turn warnings of your compiler on: `unsigned char name = "Person_name";` will make it complain a lot!

Comment: ...and many more warnings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, here

```
personArray = (Person *)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

You probably want `sizeof(Person)` instead of `sizeof(int)`. Furthermore, you seem to have some confusion with `char` and strings. This here:

```
unsigned char name = "Person_name";
```

Attempts to assign a string literal to a `char`. Your compiler should issue a warning. Instead this should be `unsigned char *name`. And also make the `name` in `Person` a pointer. Also note that this makes no copy. If you wanted a copy of the strings, do this instead:

```
unsigned char *name = "Person_name";
personArray[i].name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
strcpy(personArray[i].name, name);
```

If you do this, free the string when you're done using it, such as after you print it:

```
free(personArray[i].name);
```

And (either way) when you're done, don't forget to free the memory of `personArray`:

```
free(personArray);
```

Comment: ...and then don't forget to allocate memory for the `name` in `person` and to copy the string.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie that's right. As it is now, it wouldn't be a copy. Of course, it's not clear if OP wanted a copy.

Comment: ...and `free(pesonArray[i].name)`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That was already in the answer, but I put it on its own line now so it's more visible.

Comment: why I have to turn the property 'name' of Person into a pointer?

Comment: Because you can't assign a string to one `char`. Instead, strings are represented by a pointer to a null-terminated sequence of chars.

Comment: @LuanRibeiro, you don't have to. You can turn it into an array of char. But it cannot be a single char, as you have now in your solution (again: turn warnings of your compiler on).

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks everyone.